# Parse website in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-7.1

I found that after some modification I can use Html Agility Pack for parsing websites in WP7. I can use LINQ but not XPath. I want to ask if there is some other (maybe) better way to parse websites in WP7 and if there si some tutorial. Thanks

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is just fine. Besides, not that difficult to write the LINQ instead of XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scraping websites is generally a bad idea, unless you control them, as they can change their structure faster than you can update your app.

If you are scraping your own site you'd be better off building an API to expose the data in a structure way that better meets your applications requirements.

If you really must do this then the HtmlAgilityPack is the best solution currently available.

If you really must do this then you'll give your users a faster, better experieince by building your own web service which acts as a proxy between your app and the other site.
The advantages of this are:
- needing to connect to the website less often (probably - assuming you can cache the parsed page)
- faster parsing of the site/page/data
- A faster app (as it has to do less processing
- less data needing to be sent to the app

Comment: It is not my website and there is no API for that website so I must do it this way.

Comment: Then check you have permission to scrape their site.

Comment: Do you have link to article about building web service which acts as a proxy between your app and the other site?